# PHP Join multiple tables not working as expected

Tags: php, join, left-join, inner-join

I'll explain briefly what I've done so far-
First of all I have multiple of stores and each store has its own table in which it contains *id,item,qty and price* and there is a main table called `all_items` that contains the total qty taken from each store table.

Now each store table either have same item number or not. Here you can see what the tables looks like :

Store tables called : S1, S2, S3

**S1**

```
id item qty price
1  x1   10  12
2  x2   10  15
3  x3   5   5
```

**S2**

```
id item qty price
1  x1   10  12
2  x4   6   6
```

**S3**

```
id item qty price
1  x3   1   5
2  x6   5   5
3  x7   5   12
```

**all_items** - *Contains original total qty*

```
id item qty price
1  x1   20  12
2  x2   10  15
3  x3   6   5
4  x4   6   6
5  x6   5   5
6  x7   5   12
```

Okay now, I've decided to find out the qty available for each item in all stores for comparing purposes- As follows :

```
item price S1  S2  S3
x1   12    10  10  -
x2   15    10  -   -
x3   5     5   -   5
x4   6     -   6   -
x6   5     -   -   5
x7   12    -   -   5
```

I hope its clear for you now. I've created a form with checkbox input type ( for each store ) to allow user select which stores he wants to compare, so after submitting the form - a PHP page contains the following code :

```
$allstore = $_POST['store']; //Collects name from checkbox ticks under form


 function createSelect($allstore)
{
    if (empty($allstore))
        return "";

    $querySelect = "";
    $queryJoin = "";
    $baseTable = "";
    foreach ($allstore as $store => $value) {
        if (!$querySelect) {
            $baseTable = "all_items";
            $querySelect = "SELECT " . $store . ".item_no, " . $store . ".actual_price, " . $store . ".selling_price, " . $store . ".qty as " . $store;
        } else {
            $querySelect .= ", " . $store . ".qty as " . $store;
            $queryJoin .= "
            INNER JOIN " . $store . " ON " . $baseTable . ".item_no = " . $store . ".item_no";
        }
    }
    $querySelect .= " FROM " . $baseTable;
    $query = $querySelect . $queryJoin;

    return $query;
}


$allstore = array(); // The below code allows function to know how many stores selected in $allstore 
if (!empty($_POST['store'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['store'] as $value) {
         $allstore["s_".$value] = 0; // or 1, it doesn't matter because your function adds all the keys
    }
}

var_dump(createSelect($allstore)); // Output SQL 

$query = (createSelect($allstore)); 
$result = mysql_query($query);
//Rest of the code .....
```

Now if you notice `$baseTable = "all_items";` makes the whole query fail. However if I change it value to `$baseTable = $store;` it works and shows an output but not as expected because it turns out S1 is the main now and the result will be totally different because it relays on the S1 items only.

If you can provide any helpful solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `UNION`?

```
function createSelect($stores)
{
    $query = "";
    $baseTable = "all_items";
    foreach($stores as $i => $store)
    {
        $query .= "(SELECT {$store}.id AS {$store}_id, {$store}.item AS {$store}_item, {$store}.price AS {$store}_price, {$store}.qty AS {$store}_qty, '{$store}' as Source FROM {$store}) UNION ";
    }
    $query .= "(SELECT all_items.id AS {$baseTable}_id, {$baseTable}.item AS {$baseTable}_item, {$baseTable}.price AS {$baseTable}_price, {$baseTable}.qty AS {$baseTable}_qty, '{$baseTable}' as Source FROM {$baseTable})";
    return $query; 
}

$result = mysql_query(createSelect($allStore));
//Rest of code
//if my tables are S1, S1, and my $baseTable is bs
//echo createSelect(array('S1', 'S2'); will output (SELECT S1.id AS S1_id, S1.item AS S1_item, S1.price AS S1_price, S1.qty AS S1_qty, 'S1' as Source FROM S1) UNION (SELECT S2.id AS S2_id, S2.item AS S2_item, S2.price AS S2_price, S2.qty AS S2_qty, 'S2' as Source FROM S2) UNION (SELECT all_items.id AS all_items_id, all_items.item AS all_items_item, all_items.price AS all_items_price, all_items.qty AS all_items_qty, 'all_items' as Source FROM all_items)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, according to your code I'm getting an mysqli error `-mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`

Comment: Its seems hopeless finding a solution for this.

Comment: I replicated your case at my end and it seems to work well. Check to see if column names and table names corresponds to what you already have. If it doesn't still, let me know

Comment: The one problem I noticed was that results from multiple `SELECT` queries with `UNION` are indistinguishable as you can't tell which table a column is from even with **aliases** so I have edited my answer again with that in mind adding another columns to tell where a row is from. The error you got means either the query is not properly formatted or table or column names are incorrect. Please, check against this errors and try again.